# Save function not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem I can't save data to database this is my Laravel code
**My Store Function**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $courses                         =   new onlinecoursesController;
    $courses->title                  =   request('title');
    $courses->short_description      =   request('short_description');
    $courses->level                  =   request('level');
    $courses->date                   =   request('date');
    $courses->time                   =   request('time');
    $courses->duration               =   request('duration');
    $courses->confrence_type         =   request('confrence_type');
    $courses->zoom_id                =   request('zoom_id');
    $courses->zoom_password          =   request('zoom_password');
    $courses->youtube_stream_url     =   request('youtube_stream_url');

    $courses->save();

}
```

When I try to save it show me this error

```
BadMethodCallException -- Method App\Http\Controllers\onlinecoursesController::save does not exist.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... I would assume you want to be setting the attributes and saving a Model not a Controller?

Comment: exactly i have a form and i want to save it

Comment: does your controller (Entity?) have such a method?

Comment: Because `onlinecoursesController` is a controller, not a model. You need to save your values in whatever model you created.

Comment: what is the name of your model?

Comment: Have you read any documentation before starting?

Comment: my model name is onlinecourses inside it i have this code <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class onlinecoursesController extends Model
{
    //
}

Comment: Then you're going to have to specify which onlinecoursesController you're using. If you look at the message `App\Http\Controllers\onlinecoursesController::save`, it's trying to use the controller in `App\Http\Controllers`, not in `App`. Precede the model name with the full namespace. And rethink your naming structure, it's confusing to have both a model and a controller with the exact same name.

Comment: @Redone Could you please share content of `onlinecoursesController`?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, `save` method is not supported by controllers, it's a function of a **model object**.

Please read the [Laravel Documentation.](https://laravel.com)